# Fetch array values using foreach from ajax response

Tags: jquery

Hi guys this is result array from ajax response

```
[{"qty":1,"name":"7-test-Professional","part_number":"12231","list_price":"800"},
{"qty":1,"name":"Senior Professional Forester","part_number":"","list_price":"97.000000"]
```

where i am trying to alert each value as

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getdata.php?product_id='+rate_id,
    success: function(data)
    {    
        // console.log(result);
        result=$.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(result, function( index, value ) {
            alert( index + ": " + value );
        });
        //alert(result); //this prints the above array !!               
    }
});
```

getting output as : `index_value: [object Object]`

Thanks for your time.. :)

Comment: `alert( index + ": " + JSON.stringify(value));`?

Comment: Thanks its printing as   0: {"qty":1,"name":"7-test-Professional Forester Hour","part_number":"1231231","list_price":"800.000000","sale_price":"800.000000","total_price":"800.000000"} to get individual i should use value.qty right?

Comment: its working great!! thanks raina77ow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **dataType: 'json'** into your ajax parameters
You wouldn't need parseJSON I hope.

The final code becomes

```
       $.ajax(
          {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getdata.php?product_id='+rate_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {    
              $.each(result, function( index, value ) {
                   alert( index + ": " + value );
              });           
            }
        });
```